# Serialize parquet data with C#

Tags: c#, apache, parquet

Is there a way to serialize data in Apache Parquet format using C#, I can't find any implementation of that. In the oficial Parquet docs it is said that "Thrift can be also code-genned into any other thrift-supported language." but I'm not sure what this actually means.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have started an opensource project for .NET implementation of Apache Parquet, so anyone is welcome to join. https://github.com/aloneguid/parquet-dotnet

Comment: We've just released first stable version

Comment: Thank you, we will take a look at this

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your project. I'm able to write a parquet file and read it with your appy. However, when I try to append more conent to the parquet file, I get a exception "unable to read the sequence" when trying to open it for appending. I set the memory stream position to 0 and then initialize ParquetWritter with append setting set to true:        ms.Position = 0;

            using (var writer = new ParquetWriter(schema, ms, append: true))

Comment: do you mind raising an issue on GitHub? happy to help.

Comment: I tried the project when you posted the solution, We are able to serialize parquet files. However, if we open the file again to append more row groups, it raises an exception on the reading phase, so we cannot append more data. The files can be read however by Spark in HDFS.

Comment: @dhalfageme feel free to raise an issue ;)

Answer (score 9):

We've just open sourced our .NET wrapper around Apache Parquet C++. It's a different approach compared to Parquet.NET, the latter being a pure .NET implementation.

You're welcome to give it a try and share your feedback:
https://github.com/G-Research/ParquetSharp

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one to the list. [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.Parquet/) - an open source library, can do parquet files read and write.

**Method 1: POCO Method**

Define POCO class

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Serialization code

```
List<EmployeeRecSimple> objs = new List<EmployeeRecSimple>();

Employee rec1 = new Employee();
rec1.Id = 1;
rec1.Name = "Mark";
objs.Add(rec1);
 
Employee rec2 = new Employee();
rec2.Id = 2;
rec2.Name = "Jason";
objs.Add(rec2);
 
using (var parser = new ChoParquetWriter<Employee>("emp.parquet"))
{
    parser.Write(objs);
}
```

**Method 2: Dynamic Method**

```
List<ExpandoObject> objs = new List<ExpandoObject>();
dynamic rec1 = new ExpandoObject();
rec1.Id = 1;
rec1.Name = "Mark";
objs.Add(rec1);
 
dynamic rec2 = new ExpandoObject();
rec2.Id = 2;
rec2.Name = "Jason";
objs.Add(rec2);
 
using (var parser = new ChoParquetWriter("emp.parquet"))
{
    parser.Write(objs);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm author of this library

Comment: This library wraps around Parquet.Net.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. I've spent a week trying to write my own parquet writer for .NET and it's just too complicated i.e. needs much more time. I ended up using Python and fastparquet library to do any processing outside of Hadoop clusters. I must say fastparquet is an amazing piece of work and very easy to work with but there is a lot of functionality missing i.e. nested columns and ability to effectively append to the file. Not mentioning dependency on Python3 which can be a headache to deploy.

You can generate Thrift protocols into C# but that doesn't get you far, it just means your output will be compatible with Parquet specification.

I'm still keen to create an opensource Parquet library for .NET Core/.NET 4.5 so if anyone is keen to cooperate please let me know.